# After effects Trapcode Tao put image inside the sphere

Tags: after-effects, 3d

I'm using Trapcode Tao plugin for an audio reactor sphere . Now the only view of my sphere is depended on the `Material & Lighting > Image Based Lighting > Built-in Environment`  and it is `Dark Industrial` mode

This Screenshot :

[image]

I just want to know is there a way to use an image (custom image) instead of this `Environment` inside the sphere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found a solution from the [official Red Giant documentation](https://www.redgiant.com/user-guide/trapcode-tao/tao-material-lighting/)

> If Built-in Environment is set to None, you can choose a layer to use as a custom reflection map using the **Reflection Environment** Map pop-up menu. **Any image can be selected**, but to make a correct environment map it should be a spherical map (also called a “lat/long map” or an “equirectangular map.” Note that a “sphere map” is something else). Note that using a very large environment map uses a lot of space on the GPU.

Just import your image and select it from **Reflection Environment** menu

`Material & Lighting > Image Based Lighting > Reflection Environment`

[image]